# Replace a multiply a number but another column in python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to search a column in the database in python and replace with a calculation so multiply a number by another column in that row e.g

If you find 0 in other test column replace with (2 x score result)

- Ben (replace 0)2 * 59 so it should update the Other Tests with 118 for Ben
- Bill (replace 0)2 * 28 so it should update the Other Tests with 56 for Bill

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
```

```
 Name         Score          Other Tests
Ben              59              0    
Betty            68             6
Harry            95            6 
Bill              28            0
```

Comment: There are lots of past questions showing how to update a column based on another column, and how to update rows conditional on the value of a column.

Answer (score -1):

```
df["col2"] = df.col1.apply(lambda x: x*2)
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation in your answers.